# How to use Pentaho S3 CSV input step from within a docker container?

Tags: docker, amazon-s3, etl, pentaho, aws-cli

I have set up Pentaho 9.1 and the AWS CLI in a docker container as well as defined relevant AWS environment variables from within the docker-compose file. Running `aws s3 ls` from within the container shell confirms that the environment variables have been set up properly since it does list my S3 buckets. However, when using the S3 CSV input step in Pentaho, the job run fails until I  manually enter the AWS CLI configuration settings within the container shell by running `aws configure` and entering the AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY and AWS_DEFAULT_REGION.

It seems like a Pentaho bug although I am not sure. Has anybody faced a similar issue?

Thanks,
Seb

Comment: Can you please share your transformation or job?